# change button content dinamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'have a `datagrid`  with one `DatagridTemplateColumn`  and some `DataGridTexColumn` .

Into `DatagridTemplateColumn`  I Insert a button into `HeaderTemplate`  and into `CellTemplate` .

On click button on `HeaderTemplate`  I need that all Content Button into `CellTemplate`  change

XAML

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
 <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <Button Name ="BCAll" Height="20" Width="20" Background="White" Click="BCAll_Click" Content="" />
  </DataTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
 <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  <DataTemplate x:Name="BCS">
   <Button Name ="BCSing" Height="20" Width="20" Background="White" Click="BCSing_Click" Content=""/>
  </DataTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

c#:

```
private void BCAll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button bot = (Button)sender;
    if (bot.Content == "")
    {
        bot.Content = ((char)0x221A).ToString();
        for (int i = 0; i < DTG_Can.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            Button CBM = DTG_Can.Columns[0].GetCellContent(DTG_Can.Items[i]) as Button;
            CBM.Content = ((char)0x221A).ToString();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < DTG_Can.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            Button CBM = DTG_Can.Columns[0].GetCellContent(DTG_Can.Items[i]) as Button;
            CBM.Content = "";
        }
    }
}
```

On click `BCAll_click`  event the system return `System.nullReferenceException`  on `CBM.Content`  istruction.

Comment: `CBM` is null. Try this: `var x = DTG_Can.Columns[0].GetCellContent(DTG_Can.Items[i])`. Put in a breakpoint and inspect the type of `x`. It isn't a Button. But this approach is entirely wrong. You should be altering the button content in the XAML, with a binding or a trigger. You could also use a ToggleButton, or a checkbox.

Comment: Can you send me an example of xaml code to alterate content with binding or trigger?

Comment: Do you have a viewmodel?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181258/iterate-loop-through-datagrid-rows-to-get-the-value-of-checkbox-column-using-sil] in this topic I found my issue

Answer (score 0):

I try to use checkbox but when i loop to see if checkbox is checked the system return the same error after 30 iteration.

```
for (int i = 0; i < DTG_Mod.Items.Count; i++)
{
 drv = (DataRowView)DTG_Mod.Items.GetItemAt(i);
 var item = DTG_Mod.Items[i];
 var CBM = DTG_Mod.Columns[0].GetCellContent(item) as CheckBox;
 if ((bool)CBM.IsChecked)
 { do something...
```

I see that 30 is the number of row that I see on my datagrid